# Windows Phone 7.1 Emulator won't launch

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7-emulator

I'm using windows 7 OS (64 bits)

I've installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 + SP1 + WP7 SDK 7.1 (Mango)

Everything worked well during the installation but when I launch the emulator (inside VS 2010) it crashes:

I have a windows dialog box saying that the emulator has stopped working:

[image]

Any help please ? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have a [DirectX 10 or above capable graphics card with a WDDM 1.1 driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570)? Have you completely uninstalled any pre-release version of the Windows Phone SDK 7.1?

Comment: I have this graphics card: Mobile Intel (R) 4 series express chipset family and directX 11 (according to the dxdiag ), is it compatible ?

Comment: I haven't installed any pre-release version of the Windows Phone SDK 7.1

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert, I only asked a question based on the system requirements of the SDK.

Comment: @Siho Have you tried to check in Event Viewer to find some errors?

Comment: @verdesrobert Thank you for the advice. I don't have that PC anymore (so I can't check for now) but I'm pretty sure that I've already looked into the Event Viewer and found nothing suspicious... You're talking about windows event viewer right?

Comment: @Siho Yes about Windows Event Viewer